# Script uses a lot of Ram if it's running long

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have a PS Script (running all the time on a Powershell 3.0) and there is a loop, which consumes many RAM.

```
while(1)
{
$te = Get-Winevent -MaxEvents 1 -FilterHashtable @{logname='application';id=2}| select -expand properties
Sleep 1
}
```

I tried to delete the Object and call the GC explicit. But nothing works! The Script is consuming a lot of RAM

How can I solve this Issue?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your code, it seems that you want to find all events in the Application event log with the ID of 2.  If so, you're going about it wrong.  You should use the Get-EventLog cmdlet.  Try this:

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Application -InstanceID 2
```